# set the css class of a form widget based on the data

Tags: django, django-forms

The `attrs` attribute of a widget allows to define the html attributes. For example, setting it to `widget.attrs['class'] = 'class1 class2'` will add `class="class1 class2"` on the rendered widget.

However, how can I set them based on the data? I display an update form and I'd like to change the CSS class based on the data that is going to be displayed when the form is rendered.

Where could I check for the data in order to change the `attrs` property of the widget before it is rendered?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have the data in your context, so you should be able to do {% if %} testing the data you want to change the class

Comment: Thank you for your solution. However, I defined a custom field and widget classes because there are other things going on so I'd like to avoid this solution of adding some logic in the template if possible. I'd like to maybe add this login in either my custom field or custom widget but not sure where exactly.